# Pass Html String from Controller to View ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Which is the best way to pass the Html String block from Controller to View in MVC. I want it display that html block at the page load. Thank you. It can be any Html,
e.g

```
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to pass this as a string from controller to View. where it will be displayed as an html.

**Thank you**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Passing Raw HTML from Controller to View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033578/asp-net-mvc-passing-raw-html-from-controller-to-view)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In your controller action :

```
ViewBag.HtmlStr = "<table style=\"width:300px\"><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td> <td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr></table>";
```

Your view :

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HtmlStr)
```

Comment: Simple solution and simple is the best.

Comment: helped me too .. super

Comment: Be careful with `Html.Raw()` like this...  a hacker could use this as a potential failure point...

Answer (score 7):

You can assign the html in controller to ViewBag and access the ViewBag in View to get the value that is the html

*Controller*

```
ViewBag.YourHTML = htmlString;
```

*View*

```
<div> @ViewBag.YourHTML </div>
```

Its better to **not** to pass the html from *controller to View* rather pass the object or collection of object to View (strongly typed view) and render html in View as it is responsibility of View

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult YourView()
{
    //YourCode
    return View(entities.yourCollection.ToList());
}
```

*Veiw*

```
<table style="width:300px">
    foreach (var yourObject in Model)
    {
       <tr>
             <td>@yourObject.FirstName</td>
             <td>@yourObject.LasttName</td> 
             <td>@yourObject.Amount</td>
       </tr>      
    }

</table>
```

Comment: and how should i display it in view

Comment: Good answer Adil, but I really dislike the practice of creating html in a controller. Thats what views are for :)

Comment: No Dude, this will only show that Html as a normal string. I want to display it as an Html

Comment: Well it depends, its better to use the stongly typed views

Comment: @Sandman You are right bro, But sometimes you are stuck to do so.. Cant help.

Comment: @Pratik I feel your pain :)

Answer (score 2):

Best approach will be to create a partial view and append the html returned by it in your parent view inside some container div.

In your main view do like this:

```
<div>

    @{

    Html.RenderAction("youraction","yourcontroller")

     }

</div>
```

in your action do this:

```
public ActionResult youraction()
{
 return View();
}
```

and your partial view:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my html which is going to come is not static, its totally dynamic. so i cant create a fixed partial view.

Comment: you can create dynamic html in partial view\

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
 ViewBag.HTMLData = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlString);
```

View

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ViewBag.HTMLData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewBag.YourField` or `ViewData["YourStringName"]` and for retreiving it in your View. Just place it where you want preceded by `@` like this `@ViewBag.YourField` or `@ViewData["YourStringName"]`.