# ASP Core MVC: Pass Html String from Controller into View with variables

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, view, .net-core-2.0

I would like to pass Variables into an HTML screen and place on the screen. Currently using Net Core.

This question is only for regular .Net and does not seem to work.
[Pass Html String from Controller to View ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781548/pass-html-string-from-controller-to-view-asp-net-mvc)

**Test Controller:**

```
_cardtitle = "Green Tree Title";
_cardtext = "Oak tree with leaves";
_imageurl = "https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"

public IActionResult Test(string _cardtitle, string _cardtext)
{

    ViewBag.CardTitle = _cardtitle;
    ViewBag.CardText = _cardtext;
    ViewBag.ImageURL= _imageurl;

    ViewBag.Cardstring = @"<div class=""card"" style=""width: 18rem;"" >
<img class=""card -img-top"" src =""https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"" alt =""Card image cap"" >
<div class=""card -body"" >
    <h5 class=""card -title"" > @ViewBag.CardTitle</h5>
    <p class=""card -text"">@ViewBag.CardText</p>
</div>
</div>";
    return View();
}
```

**Test.cshtml**

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Cardstring)
```

Right now I only see @ Ampersand Variables,

[image: Picture HTML Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying your ViewBag wrong.

Change `Html.Raw(ViewBag.Cardtest)` to `Html.Raw(ViewBag.Cardstring)`

EDIT:
According to my comments this should work for you. You need to pass `@ViewBag.CardTitle` and `@ViewBag.CardText` as properties not as part of string.

```
ViewBag.Cardstring = "<div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 180rem;\"><img class=\"card -img-top\" src =\"https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60\" alt =\"Card image cap\"><div class=\"card -body\" ><h5 class=\"card -title\" >" + @ViewBag.CardTitle +"</h5><p class=\"card -text\">" + @ViewBag.CardText + "</p></div></div>";
```

Comment: sorry just fixed my question code, but does not solve underyling issue yet, same result

Comment: Remove `@` while assigning raw html to `ViewBag.Cardstring` in Controller

Comment: this will cause syntax errors, need to contain html

Comment: Yes you need to add \ in front of double "